# interpolate node attributes of a network

Tags: r, interpolation, igraph

**BLUF: I am looking for an existing function, or  general algorithm I could develop into a function, to interpolate node attributes along a graph.**

Consider the following graph:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

set.seed(40)

g = create_lattice(c(8, 8), TRUE, TRUE) %N>%
  mutate(
    value = if_else(
      runif(n()) > 0.5, 
      rnorm(n(), 50, 15), 
      NA_real_
    )
  ) %E>%
  mutate(length = abs(rnorm(n(), 5, 3))) %E>%
  filter(runif(n()) > 0.25)

ggraph(g) + theme_void() + 
  geom_edge_link2(arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')),
    end_cap = circle(3, 'mm')) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(color = value), size = 5)
```

[image]

I would like to interpolate the missing node attributes based on their neighbors. Ideally, the interpolation would factor in both the edge weights (e.g. a distance or length) as well as the edge direction, and would optionally be able to extrapolate by a constant value (i.e. similar to how `approx(..., rule = 2)` works). I don't have a particular preference for the specific type of interpolation (I would be happy with linear interpolation, inverse distance weighting, etc.) but I'm having a really hard time finidng or conceptualizing an algorithm.

Is there a node attribute interpolation algorithm that works with `igraph` or `tidygraph` already available in R, or are there published algorithms that could be implemented in R without too much trouble?

Answer (score 0):

For small graphs, you can generate the distance matrix and use that as the basis of an inverse distance weighting approach. You can compute the distance matrix using edge directions (or not) and weights (or not):

```r
library(igraph)
E(g)$weight = E(g)$length
d = distances(g, mode = "out")

n = vector("numeric", ncol(d))

for (i in 1:ncol(d)){
  w = d[,i]^(-3) 
  w[!(d[,i] > 0)] = 0
  n[i] = sum(w * V(g)$value, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(w, na.rm = TRUE)
}

g.new = g %N>%
  mutate(interpolated = is.na(value)) %N>%
  mutate(value = if_else(interpolated, n, value))

ggraph(g.new) + theme_void() + 
  geom_edge_link2(arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')),
    end_cap = circle(3, 'mm')) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(color = value, shape = interpolated), size = 5)
```

[image]